# Deploying TLS cert with QT qrc

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, qml, qt5

I'm trying to include a SSL cert in the app deployment so we can connect to our server securely. I am able to add the files into our asset folder and our resources.qrc file and it works with debug deployment. However when I try to make a release build, it breaks and is unable to find the files.

I've ripped through the QT docs and SO, but everything I've tried has not worked.

Here is the excerpt from the .pro file:

```
`qmlFolder.source = qml
 DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS += qmlFolder # comment for publishing

assetsFolder.source = assets
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS += assetsFolder

# Add more folders to ship with the application here

QT += xml svg quick qml widgets

# resources.qrc

RESOURCES += resources.qrc # uncomment for publishing`
```

Here is my resources.qrc file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qml</file>
        <file>GandiStandardSSLCA2.crt</file>
        <file>SSLcomDVCA_2.crt</file>
    </qresource> </RCC>
```

Here is where I set the path: `certPath = "://SSLcomDVCA_2.crt"; // Dev Cert`

I got the path from right clicking the file. Again it works in a debug build, but not for release, so I believe it's not being packaged properly. Any hints or ideas how to proceed resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to re-run qmake and full rebuild of the project for release build?

Comment: Yes, I removed build folder entirely, restarted QT and my computer and tried rebuilding with qmake several times, still have the same issue.

Comment: Can you look at the generated file qrc_<proname>.cpp in the build folder and see if there is any text in comments similar to SSLcomDVCA_2.crt ? You can compare the file in your debug and release folders.

Comment: Looking at the specified file, they are identical in both the debug and release output folders

Comment: Somwhere in the main() after QApplication instantiation check a list of resource files that your app actually has in :/ folder with QDir(":/").entryList(). What files are there? And as the last attempt why don't you try to init the resource explicitly with Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resources) and see if anything changes.

Comment: Implemented the QDir check, and the debug build shows all the items in the qrc resource that I expect, including the certificate file. Also explicitly initiated the resource file and it doesn't seem to change the output of the QDir command.

Comment: Well, in release build there is an empty list? One more suggestion. It might appear that there is another resources.qrc file with the same name in you project, in some of the linked shared libraries, perhaps. If it the case then only one resource file of the same name is loaded and there is a race condition and in debug mode wins your file and in release mode wins the other file. Try to rename the qrc file to some unique name like blahblablah1112.qrc, edit .pro accordingly, re-run qmake and rebuild. Hope, it will help, I don't have any other idea.

Comment: I haven't been able to check that. I tried running the debugger in the release version, but it keeps crashing. I'm working on a temp messagedialog to pop up a message dialog with the list.

What I'll do to your second point is create a new .qrc file that only contains the certs so I know for sure they are being loaded. 

Thanks again for all your suggestions

Comment: Why don't you use qDebug() for temporary logging out the debugging info? You would see the debugging messages in Qt Creator Application output console.

Comment: I tried using qDebug for a temporary use, but the release build doesn't output in the `Application Output` as I would like it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the "issue" and the answer to my problem. Although I think the problem would be a QT bug or my understanding of string definition is wrong. I set the resource file called `certs.qrc` when I put the two certificates for dev and prod. I created the file definition and used the path I got by right clicking on the resource file and copying it's path. See below for the full definition of the SSL, hopefully this will serve as an example for QT SSL as well because I could barely find any of those either.

Here is my certs file without the 'RCC' header because it seems to break block quotes:

> ```
> <qresource prefix="/certs">
>     <file>GandiStandardSSLCA2.crt</file>
>     <file>SSLcomDVCA_2.crt</file>
> </qresource>
> ```

Below is the definition for that certificate file:

> ```
> // SSL socket set up
> QFile certFile(":/certs/GandiStandardSSLCA2.crt");
> if(certFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
> {
>     qDebug() << "File opened";
> }
> else {
>     qDebug() << "Boooo";
> }
> QSslCertificate cert(&certFile, QSsl::Pem);
> forgotPwSocket = new QSslSocket(this);
> forgotPwSocket->addCaCertificate(cert);
> ```

All this is currently functional. make sure you run qmake in order to get the resource files compiled.

So now, my explanation as to why I was having a problem. I was using a different deploy method before for the certs where I was deploying the entire assets folder. That works for Android by not iOS so I decided to go with qrc instead. While I was trying to implement the `/assets` folder deployment I was using an **ifdef to define the string of the path depending on if it was iOS or Android.** I removed the ifdef, and all my problems went away, it was now able to find the files at the path. The string is a member of my network object and I would define it at run time using the ifdef. During all my debugging, it was the correct path as shown in the inspector. Realizing that using the .qrc resource eliminated the need to define the path based on Android/iOS I hardcoded the path value as stated above. Once I did that, it started working. The path name is the same as it was in the debugger with the ifdef in place so I'm not sure why/where this was breaking. If anyone has any further insight it would be fantastic to hear. Hopefully this will help anyone having a similar issue or getting SSL working in QT in general!